# Pandas: add new column with count how often the highest score of a day was reached by this person

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

It is pandas/Dataframe, it contains all scores for everyone everyday, I want to add one extra column to collect how many time it has the highest score (could be more than one people and some data are `nan`)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = np.array([['','day1','day2','day3','day4','day5'],
                ['larry',1,4,7,3,5],
                ['niko',2,-1,3,6,4],
                ['tin',np.nan,5,5, 6,7]])
                
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data[1:,1:],
                  index=data[1:,0],
                  columns=data[0,1:])
print(df)
```

output

```
      day1 day2 day3 day4 day5
larry    1    4    7    3    5
niko     2   -1    3    6    4
tin    nan    5    5    6    7
```

expected result is (larry: 1 time, niko: 2 times, tin: 3 times)

```
      times_of_top day1 day2 day3 day4 day5
larry            1    1    4    7    3    5
niko             2    2   -1    3    6    4
tin              3  nan    5    5    6    7
```

`niko` has the highest score on `day1` and `day4` so his `times_of_top` is 2.
`tin` has the highest score on `day2`, `day4` and `day5` so his `times_of_top` is 3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way using `pandas.DataFrame.stack` and `count`:

```
# df = df.astype(float)
# Since the sample data are in object type

df["times_of_top"] = df[df == df.max()].stack().count(0)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
       day1  day2  day3  day4  day5  times_of_top
larry   1.0   4.0   7.0   3.0   5.0             1
niko    2.0  -1.0   3.0   6.0   4.0             2
tin     NaN   5.0   5.0   6.0   7.0             3
```

Comment: @LarryCai - did you convert to float as in the comment

Comment: no, but ok as answer. @Chris can update it.